# Image in UI doesn't update when using State Hooks

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, expo

I have a state hook variable defined as follows:

```js
const [imageURL, setimageURL] = useState(null);
```

I am using expo-image-picker to get an image from my gallery and upload it to firebase storage. I then get the URL of this image and update the value of imageURL accordingly.

```
const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
        allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [4, 3],
        quality: 1,
    });

    console.log(result);

    if (!result.cancelled) {
        uploadImage(result.uri, 'Profile-picture')
            .then(() => {
                console.log('it work')
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('it does not work')
                console.error(error)
            })
            
    }       
}   

const uploadImage = async (uri, imageName) => {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser
    const currentUser = user.uid
    const response = await fetch(uri)
    const blob = await response.blob()

    const ref = firebase.storage().ref(currentUser + '/profilePicture/' + imageName)
    ref.put(blob)
    ref.getDownloadURL()
        .then((url) => {
            setimageURL(url)
            setLocalStorage(url)
        })
}
```

When the page first loads the value is null so there is a blank icon. Once I upload the image and get the URL the UI on my app does not update to show the new image. It will stay blank unless I upload another new image. Once this happens the UI will update but it will now show the image that I first uploaded. Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong?

Note: I even tried added a text component and passed in imageURL variable to display the current URL and for some reason this text updates properly but the image does not. (not shown here)

```
 return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <KeyboardAwareScrollView
            style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%' }}
            keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
        <Avatar
            size="xlarge" 
            rounded
            source={{
                uri: imageURL
            }}
            icon={{ name: 'user', type: 'font-awesome' }}
            activeOpacity={0.7}
            containerStyle={{alignSelf: 'center', backgroundColor: '#89CFF0', marginTop: 50}}
        >
        </Avatar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are using the image source in a child component.
Child component gets constructed using the initial state of imageURL that is null.
When the state updates in parent, child component i.e `<Avatar>` is not aware of this update and is not re-rendered. It is not advised to pass initial state value to child components. But if you can't avoid it here is a trick.
Add key to your Avatar component

```js
const [imageKey, setimageKey] = useState(1);
```

```js
<Avatar 
  size="xlarge" 
  rounded 
  source={{ uri: imageURL }} 
  icon={{ name: 'user', type: 'font-awesome' }} 
  activeOpacity={0.7} 
  containerStyle={{alignSelf: 'center', backgroundColor: '#89CFF0', 
  marginTop: 50}} 
  key={imageKey}
> </Avatar>
```

And update the key everytime new imageUrl is fetched:

```js
const uploadImage = async (uri, imageName) => { 
  const user = firebase.auth().currentUser 
  const currentUser = user.uid const response = await fetch(uri) 
  const blob = await response.blob() 
  const ref = firebase.storage().ref(currentUser + '/profilePicture/' 
        + imageName) ref.put(blob) ref.getDownloadURL() 
  .then((url) => { 
    setimageURL(url) 
    setLocalStorage(url) 
    setimageKey(prev => prev +1)
  }
 ) 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This solution worked out for me. Just curious, when you say that it is not advised to pass initial state value to child components what would be the alternative option? Should state value be used in some other component instead?